# Как установить SSL-сертификат?

Tags: node.js, ssl, koa.js

Мое приложение написано с помощью koa.js.
Я хочу сделать обычный https сервер в node.js и в качестве обработчика запроса использовать его:

```
const https = require('https');

var key = fs.readFileSync('encryption/private.key');
var cert = fs.readFileSync( 'encryption/primary.crt' );
var ca = fs.readFileSync( 'encryption/intermediate.crt' );

 var options = {
  key: key,
  cert: cert,
  ca: ca
 };


 const Koa = require('koa');
 const app = new Koa();

 https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Правильно ли это? И reg.ru прислал мне на почту несколько ключей, не могу понять как извлечь из них нужное (private.key, primary.crt, intermediate.crt).

Данные от reg.ru:

```
 1) Ваш сертификат предоставлен ниже
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...

 2) Корневой сертификат

 3) Промежуточный сертификат

 4)Запрос на получение сертификата
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
  ...

 5)Сохраните приватный ключ на локальном компьютере. 
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      ...
```

Comment: Если reg.ru прислал **приватный** ключ на **почту**, то это всё можно сразу выкидывать в мусорку, потому что ключ скомпрометирован и использовать его нельзя. Приватный ключ не должен знать никто кроме вас и вашего сервера - даже reg.ru не имеет права знать его и тем более присылать куда-то

Comment: @andreymal как тогда правильно установить ssl сертификат на сервер с одной только node js